# How to check the list of users and their password via SSH

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, command, centos6

I have only root access to SSH my CentOS VPS. I have listed out all the users using awk command awk -F':' '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd

It's displaying the list of users but how to check the password of those users?

Comment: You want to see what the password actually is? You can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Passwords are typically stored encrypted in `/etc/shadow` as it is a major security issue to store them unprotected.

Check
- http://linux.die.net/man/5/shadow
- http://linux.die.net/man/5/passwd
- http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/shadow-file-formats.html

Comment: Yes, I found the list inside /etc/shadow after making couple of search in Google. They seems one way encryption so no option to decrypt them. Is there any way to know the encryption type? 
As I set the pass phrases so I found some way to match the encrypted pass phrases.

Comment: This is done by the `crypt` function. Check http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html for further details. Using the contents of `/etc/shadow`, you could verify whether a given string is a valid password.